# How can I subtract one column value from another when duplicating rows?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking for some help to try and workout how I can subtract values from 2 columns and then use the result as the new value for one of them. After this I would like to duplicate the columns as I would like the 2 column values to be on separate rows and one of the values on each row to be changed to 0.

The following is an example of what I am trying to do:

CREATE TABLE SCRIPT

```
CREATE TABLE CONNECT_BY_LVL_EXAMPLE_2 (
  EMPLOYEE_ID VARCHAR2(9 BYTE),
  WORKING_TIME_MINS NUMBER,
  TRAVEL_TIME_MINS NUMBER,
  UNIQUE_JOB_NO VARCHAR2(34 BYTE)
  );

INSERT INTO CONNECT_BY_LVL_EXAMPLE_2 VALUES
  ('123456789',73,62,'VP25');
```

This then gives me the following:

```
| EMPLOYEE_ID | WORKING_TIME_MINS | TRAVEL_TIME_MINS | UNIQUE_JOB_NO |
| 123456789   | 73                | 62               | VP25          |
```

I have managed to write the code that will duplicate the rows as I would like the WORKING_TIME_MINS and TRAVEL_TIME_MINS to be on separate rows.

```
SELECT * FROM CONNECT_BY_LVL_EXAMPLE_2,
    ( 
    SELECT ROWNUM SEQ FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2
    )
WHERE
    ( TRAVEL_TIME_MINS > 0 OR SEQ = 1 )
    ;
```

which gives me the following output:

```
| EMPLOYEE_ID | WORKING_TIME_MINS | TRAVEL_TIME_MINS | UNIQUE_JOB_NO |
| 123456789   | 73                | 62               | VP25          |
| 123456789   | 73                | 62               | VP25          |
```

Now where I am stuck, is trying to subtract the TRAVEL_TIME_MINS from WORKING_TIME_MINS as the WORKING_TIME_MINS of 73 is including the TRAVEL_TIME_MINS and therefore should be 73 - 62 = 11 and I am not sure how I add this into the code.

This the FINAL OUTPUT I am trying to achieve.

```
| EMPLOYEE_ID | WORKING_TIME_MINS | TRAVEL_TIME_MINS | UNIQUE_JOB_NO |
| 123456789   | 11                | 0                | VP25          |
| 123456789   | 0                 | 62               | VP25          |
```

Hoping someone can advise.

Answer (score 0):

It would be simpler to do the calculation at the same time as repeating the rows, using a union:

```
select employee_id,
  working_time_mins - coalesce(travel_time_mins, 0) as working_time_mins,
  0 as travel_time_mins,
  unique_job_no
from connect_by_lvl_example_2
union all
select employee_id,
  0 as working_time_mins,
  travel_time_mins,
  unique_job_no
from connect_by_lvl_example_2
where travel_time_mins > 0
```

| EMPLOYEE_ID | WORKING_TIME_MINS | TRAVEL_TIME_MINS | UNIQUE_JOB_NO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456789 | 11 | 0 | VP25 |
| 123456789 | 0 | 62 | VP25 |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8112be866b175090043be3cb5a860d81) with a couple of extra rows of data.

The coalesce in the first branch is to allow for travel time being null, so that is treated as zero.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the actual working time then `UNPIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT employee_id,
       CASE activity WHEN 'WORK'   THEN time_mins ELSE 0 END AS working_time_mins,
       CASE activity WHEN 'TRAVEL' THEN time_mins ELSE 0 END AS travel_time_mins,
       unique_job_no
FROM   (
  SELECT employee_id,
         working_time_mins - travel_time_mins AS working_time_mins,
         travel_time_mins,
         unique_job_no
  FROM   connect_by_lvl_example_2
)
UNPIVOT (
  time_mins
  FOR activity IN (
    working_time_mins AS 'WORK',
    travel_time_mins  AS 'TRAVEL'
  )
)
WHERE  activity = 'WORK'
OR     time_mins > 0;
```

or, you can `CROSS JOIN` any table with two rows:

```sql
SELECT employee_id,
       CASE activity
       WHEN 'WORK' THEN working_time_mins - travel_time_mins
       ELSE 0
       END AS working_time_mins,
       CASE activity
       WHEN 'TRAVEL'
       THEN travel_time_mins
       ELSE 0
       END AS travel_time_mins,
       unique_job_no
FROM   CONNECT_BY_LVL_EXAMPLE_2
       CROSS JOIN
       (
         SELECT 'WORK' AS activity FROM DUAL UNION ALL
         SELECT 'TRAVEL' FROM DUAL
       )
WHERE  activity = 'WORK'
OR     TRAVEL_TIME_MINS > 0;
```

Which, for your sample data, both output:

> | EMPLOYEE_ID | WORKING_TIME_MINS | TRAVEL_TIME_MINS | UNIQUE_JOB_NO |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 123456789 | 11 | 0 | VP25 |
> | 123456789 | 0 | 62 | VP25 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4a90b04c8c4da83b645d7450247ed26e)*